# Grouping with child sort

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get a list of questions for a survey where the order of the questions is stored in the intersection table of the many to many relationship.
My questions are grouped into sections as well, and everything works except the sort.  It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't sort the children (questions).

Here is my query:

```
from surveyQuestion in Context.SurveyQuestions
join question in Context.Questions
on surveyQuestion.Question_ID equals question.Question_ID
where surveyQuestion.Survey_ID == surveyId
orderby surveyQuestion.SORT_ORDER
group question by surveyQuestion.SECTION into section
select new SurveySection
{
    SurveyId = surveyId,
    SectionId = section.Key,
    Questions = section.ToList()
};
```

I have tried adding `.OrderBy` to the section before the list, but in that context, the order has been lost, and I only have the question left. I can't put the sort order in the question table, since the questions are reused and may have different sort order values.

Comment: try making the new query contain Questions = section.OrderBy(x=>x.Question_ID).ToList()

Comment: @kirsteng I think I could sort by the Question_ID in that way, but I want to sort by the SORT_ORDER field in the SurveyQuestions table, not the Question_ID.

Comment: maybe change to orderby surveyQuestion.QuestionId, surveyQuestion.Sort_Order ?

Comment: The SORT_ORDER field is not available to the section group, only the fields in the question table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to make it work, but it seems like it might be the wrong way. I created a new anonymous object including my sort and the child object, then sorted on that, then selected the child object into a list.

Now my query looks like this:

```
from surveyQuestion in Context.SurveyQuestions
join question in Context.Questions 
on surveyQuestion.Question_ID equals question.Question_ID
where surveyQuestion.Survey_ID == surveyId
orderby surveyQuestion.SORT_ORDER 
group new { question, surveyQuestion.SORT_ORDER } by surveyQuestion.SECTION  into section
select new SurveySection
  {
     SurveyId = surveyId,
     SectionId = section.Key,
     Questions = section.OrderBy(q => q.SORT_ORDER)
                        .Select(q => q.question)
                        .ToList()
  };
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can remove the line `orderby surveyQuestion.SORT_ORDER` because you have to sort in the selection (`section.OrderBy(q => q.SORT_ORDER).Select(q => q.question).ToList()`). In the selection you can remove the `.ToList()` too, because you have to execute the whole query at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from surveyQuestion in Context.SurveyQuestions
join question in Context.Questions
on surveyQuestion.Question_ID equals question.Question_ID
where surveyQuestion.Survey_ID == surveyId
orderby surveyQuestion.Question_ID,surveyQuestion.SORT_ORDER
group question by surveyQuestion.SECTION into section
select new SurveySection
{
    SurveyId = surveyId,
    SectionId = section.Key,
    Questions = section.ToList()
};
```